# How to test Vue component with API data retrieval using jest-fetch-mock?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, vuejs3

I am attempting to test my Vue component that retrieves data from an API. When I wrote `mount(MyComponent)`, I received an error message indicating that `fetch` was undefined in my component. To address this issue, I imported `jest-fetch-mock` to mock the fetch request. I also added `fetchMock.resetMocks()` to the `beforeEach()` and used `fetchMock.mockResponseOnce(mockData)` before defining a wrapper. While this resolved the error, my component still failed to receive any data.

The component renders a data in list using `ul/li` items. but the mock data recived empty `<ul></ul>` element. It should receive my mock data.

```
+----------------+---------+
| Using          | Version |
+----------------+---------+
| Vue            | latest  |
| Ionicframework | latest  |
+----------------+---------+
```

Comment: Please, post the code instead of describing it, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you found a solution to your question?